# Difference between hibernate unique constraint annotation and postgresql query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, unique-constraint

I am currently using Hibernate with Postgresql.

There are some columns in my database that needs to be set with the Unique constraint.  So I went online and found two ways of doing it

Query in Postgresql:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD UNIQUE (thecolumn);
```

Hibernate annotation:

```
@Table(
   name = "foo", 
   uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"thecolumn"})}
)
```

Which is the preferred way?  Or are both ways required?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create the database from hibernate annotation ? 
then use annotation. 
Else, do it in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I do want to create the database from the hibernate annotation, but is it a good practice to add the unique constraint to my database query as well?

Comment: It can't hurt to have your unique constraint in the database, it's a safety net in case your annotation fails at her job for some reasons. Plus it'll prevent you from entering duplicate manually in the database if you have a lot of records and don't remember what you have already inserted.

Comment: Hu?
If you create the DB from Hibernate annotation, the constraint should be in your DB avec it create/update it.

Answer (score 1):

If your database will be only manipulated by software (you have to create your own verifications to avoid duplication if you don't plan to use any entity notation), you can handle unique constraint directly in software. But in order to maintain integrity i recommend to put this also in the DB. To avoid human mistakes.

If your configuration of entities updates the db each time you change your entity model DB and ENTITIES will be equals, but if not the case no one guaranties that your columns will be unique. (Unless the ID).